# How to print a random playlist that passes through the loop by adding the minutes and compare it to the user's minute input?

Tags: java, oop, for-loop, playlist

I'm trying to print a random playlist for a radio show. So it adds the minute each time it loops. So the disc jockey enters a time segment. For example, a 9 minutes playlist. I have the data below. By the way, I'm adding the minutes using the first digit(s) before the colon.

```
1016,R,Hey Jude,The Beatles,3:00,T1.MP3
1017,R,Imagine,John Lennon,3:00,T1.MP3
1023,P,Louie Louie,The Kingsmen,3:00,T1.MP3
1026,P,What's Going On,Marvin Gaye,53:00,T1.MP3
```

It should only print the first three. If it's 7 minutes, then prints the first two and as long it is near to the time segment. Either 5 minutes less or more. I just can't seem to find the if condition right. And it's not printing anything when I enter something. All I get is a blank console.

```
private void createRandomPlayList() 
{
    int randomPickTime = 0;
    int newMin = 0;
    String timeSegment = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the time segment");
    int newTimeSegment = Integer.parseInt(timeSegment);
    Collections.shuffle(radioList);
    for(Radio radioShows : radioList)
    {
        String min = radioShows.getPlayTime().substring(0,2);
        min = min.replaceAll(":$", "");
        newMin = Integer.parseInt(min);
        randomPickTime += newMin; 
        String minInStr = Integer.toString(newMin);
        if(newTimeSegment >= randomPickTime)    
        {
            if(minInStr.equalsIgnoreCase(radioShows.getPlayTime().substring(0,2)))
            {
                System.out.println(radioShows);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     if(newTimeSegment >= randomPickTime)    
    {
         if(minInStr.equalsIgnoreCase(radioShows.getPlayTime().substring(0,2)))
        {
            System.out.println(radioShows);
        }
    }
```

if you want to use that code the substring should be (0,1) only. Also I don't think thats the problem, if you remove the if statement I think it will work well.

Answer (score 0):

This seems a little overly complex, consider

```
    String min = radioShows.getPlayTime().split(":")[0];
    newMin = Integer.parseInt(min);
    randomPickTime += newMin; 
    String minInStr = Integer.toString(newMin);
    if(newTimeSegment >= randomPickTime)    
    {
         // why is this necessary?
         // if anything it should compare to **min**
         // if(minInStr.equalsIgnoreCase(radioShows.getPlayTime().substring(0,2)))
        {
            System.out.println(radioShows);
        }
    }
    else {break;}
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked. I only used the second if statement, thinking that would compare it again as a string instead of using the integer datatype.